# How to correct column with dates in MDY and text to DMY?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a column of dates extracted from a database, but the system exports the dates in MDY format. My computer works in DMY so it converts December the 2nd to February the 12ve, and November the 23rd to text. I don´t want to change the date system for my computer since I need it this way to work with all the other data I use.

I´ve donde some research and have after some thought ended up using this (Where J2 contains the date I want to convert):

> =IF(ISTEXT(J2),DATE(MID(J2,7,4),LEFT(J2,2),MID(J2,4,2))+MID(J2,12,11),DATE(YEAR(J2),DAY(J2),MONTH(J2))+MOD(J2,1))

But I would like to find simpler way of doing this.

Here is a picture of the kind of data I have and the expected result. Sorry, I cannot access Drive to share the spreadsheet at work.

[image: Sample of data and expected result]